# Printing Rails test names to find the slowest tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I'd like to find which of the tests are the slowest in my test suite based on [this](http://xplayer.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/ruby-how-to-spot-slow-tests-in-your-test-suite/) blog post. Here's the minified version of the code:

```
# test/test_time_tracking.rb
module TestTimeTracking
  class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    setup    :mark_test_start_time 
    teardown :record_test_duration

    def mark_test_start_time
      @start_time = Time.now
    end

    def record_test_duration
      puts "Test class: #{self.class.name}"
      puts "Duration:   #{Time.now - @start_time}"
    end
  end
end

# test/test_helper.rb
require 'test_time_tracking'
include TestTimeTracking
# ...
```

Is there a way to print out the test name during either the settup or teardown? In the blog post they call `name` attribute in the teardown block, but this throws an error in my case. I've also tried `@name` and `@method_name` with no success.

I'm using `shoulda-contexts` gem on top of the default Rails test framework. I know that I can get the test name and duration with `rake test TESTOPTS=-v`, but I will then have to run another script to parse the output.

Comment: Wow, more time on tests. Don't forget about your code that actually matters. ;)

Comment: @DDDD Slow tests sometimes indicate the actual code problems. Let me know if I'm wrong though :)

Answer (score 10):

Use [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters). Installation Guide is provided on this page.
After configration use rspec reporter. i.e in your test_helper.rb file write

```
Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new()]
```

And run the test. This 'll format output like this:
[image]

You can see the time taken by each test.

Answer (score 3):

```
def record_test_duration
  puts "Test class: #{self.class.name}"
  puts "Test method: #{self.method_name}"
  puts "Duration:   #{Time.now - @start_time}"
end
```

self.method_name will print the current test method name

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the some explanation of the code and its reational

Comment: I liked that you actually answered what he asked in the question

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5

```
bin/rails test -v
```

It prints something like this:

```
SimpleTest#test_: Simple should be a success.  = 0.26 s = .                                                                                                                                                
SimpleTest#test_: Simple should be a failure.  = 0.23 s = .
```